# How to query from two columns with one string in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I have two columns in the `users` table: `first_name` & `last_name`. I want to query the user search `john doe`. I attempted it like the following.

```php
$users = User::where('username', $request->text)
    ->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->text.'%')
    ->paginate(5);
```

It searches only through `john` and I don't understand how to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following...

```php
$users = User::where('username', $request->text)
    ->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) 
        LIKE ?", ['%' . $request->text . '%'])
    ->paginate(5);
```

The `whereRaw` and `orWhereRaw` methods can be used to inject a raw where clause into your query.